# Не выводит в консоль log сообщение - boost::log

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2017

Взял из документации по `boost::log` пример:

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

Запускается консоль и ничего не выводит. IDE: Visual Studio 2017. Boost 1.63.0

Comment: Сборка точно заканчивается нормально? Попробуйте добавить `#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK 1` первой строкой.